# Access Denied when Mapping Drive from Windows 7 to Samba Share

Tags: debian, network-shares, samba

I'm at my wits end with this, I've tried connecting to my samba server with smbusr, and smbusr_RO from windows 7 by mapping a drive. It says S:\ is not accessible, access denied. I know I'm putting the correct password in, for both users. I've even tried logging in as root, still no luck.

Here is my smb.conf file:

http://pastebin.com/cUGEF3yi

If you guys need more information just ask, thanks a million.

Comment: Did you run smbpass -a <user> as well? That one catches me out every time I set samba up.

Comment: I figured it out eventually, it was the underlying linux permissions. I had to 'chmod 777 /samba' which really bothers me, because now I'm worried my stuff is wide open.

Comment: Mnh, you can always force a uid+gid in the mount options and have directories 0770 and files 0660 (find -exec chmod works nicely there)